# Facebook Login Doesn't Work

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to add Facebook login to my web site.

What I have done?

1. Created APP on Facebook as `Website with Facebook Login`
2. Sandbox mode is `off`
3. APP is set to work on `localhost`.

What is the problem?

1. I keep getting `$user` variable's value as `0`
2. example.php in Facebook PHP SDK works just fine!
3. I can see my APP when I visit **Facebook -> Privacy Settings -> Apps**. No matter if I login with my `login.php` or `example.php` of **Facebook PHP SDK**, the app seems to be added just the same. However while `example.php` can retrieve data from facebook, `login.php` can't.
4. I copy and paste the codes from `example.php` to my `login.php` page (please check the code below).

Here is my code (**login.php**);

```
require_once('system/api/facebook/facebook.php');
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '123456',
  'secret' => 'abcde12345',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}

if (!$user) echo '<a href="'.$loginUrl.'">Login</a>';

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($user);
echo '</pre>';
```

Can someone please tell me what is the difference between my **login.php** and **example.php**? I also Googled and searched here without finding any info which was helpful.

Comment: Might be worth (temporarily) throwing an error inside your catch, otherwise you might find it is catching a problem and not alerting you to it.

Comment: oh, I have tried it as well... No success...

Comment: Ok I guess I figured it out, it is most probably my htaccess, URL Re-write rules....

Comment: Debugging time, then! If `$user` comes back in this code as zero, then put in some echo statements in `Facebook::getUser` to see what differences there are between this and the working example.

Comment: Thank you all! I can't believe I didn't realize the problem sooner and lost more than 5-6 hours on this simple problem already!

The problem was solved once I removed URL-Rewrite rule for a specific file. Facebook adds querystring at the end of the URL like `?code=123&status=123` and private method `getCode()` tries to access code and status values.

Thank you all for your time and concern.

Comment: @halfer once again thank you for your help and time. Considering I took your time for nothing, maybe you could add the solution as an answer (URL re-write issue was the problem) so I could accept it as a solution. At least that is what I can do for your time.

Comment: Heh, no problem Revenant, though I didn't really do anything! I've often found that, by posting a tough question on a technical forum, it has the effect of making it clearer what should be tried next, and then one gets the answer almost automatically. Pleased you fixed it `:)`.

Comment: You need an access_token from a successfull Facebook login to access anything. use $facebook->setAccessToken($mytoken) after you got one and then retry the getuser() Method.

Comment: The SDK can work without such a token, but ONLY if your PHP code can access the facebook cookie from another successfull login process. Of course it can only access that cookie if it's sitting on same Domain etc...